# http for local and https for remote. how to do?

Tags: .htaccess

How can write this pseudocode in .htaccess:

```
if (ip == "127.0.0.1") or (dns = "localhost") {
  // all to http://
} else {
  // all to https://
}
```

Shortly, need http for local and https for remote.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
 RewriteEngine on

 #if http host =127.0.0.1 or localhost
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127\.0\.0\.1$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
 #then do nothing
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 #else enforce https
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: if url in input in local is https://something i need return http://something.
If url in input in remote is http://something i need return https://something.
In all other cases not need to do nothing. So i don't think to solve it.